# Will hibernate be a overhead in case of less writes

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jakarta-ee

We are developing a application which interacts with Data-warehouse and retrieves data to do analysis.

Will Hibernate become a performance overhead in this case as there will be very less writes to the Data-warehouse.

Intention is to have loose coupling between Business Layer and Data Layer.

For this requirement will Spring JDBC be ideal than using ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM is only helpful if you actually plan on using the results as objects.  Performance should be comparable to JDBC provided you put it behind a sensible cache (ehcache).

Answer (score 2):

For more reads, I second using Spring JDBC with caching. I would first try caching at the Database level and if that is not performant enough then move to application level caching.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate may not be as efficient as a tweaked Spring JDBC but it is much easier to use and therefore gives you more productivity. In addition it probably won't a bottleneck in your application!

It is quite easy to set up so I suggest you give it a try and appreciate the time you save using it! This is probably more valuable than the few milliseconds you may save using JDBC instead...

Comment: Yeah, i understand the ease of development using ORM. But, what i am trying to understand is if it is recommended to use ORM in case of less writes.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate performs better in case of mostly read applications. 
Pay attention you might still have issue of performance due to the following: 
A. Heavy usage of object proxies 
B. The SQL generation might be good, but not optimized - I would seriously recommend her to turn on the show_sql = true property at the configuration and monitor carefully the SQL calls in some benchmarks, if you go for hibernate solution. 
To overcome B - please consider invoking stored procedures via hibernate and map the results to object (use Hibernate for object mapping, not for SQL generation) in that sense, Hibernate will become closer to Spring-JDBC in behavior. 
In addition, consider using the caching stategies of Hibernate to improve performance - not sure if this is possible in your case -
a. queries cache 
b. first level cache (at session scope) 
c. 2nd level cache - at application-wisde scope 
I also recommend to do a proper design, and have your DAL as loosely coupled as possible, so in case Hibernate does not perform well, it will be easy for you to switch to other alternatives, such as Spring-JDBC